# C function of linked list wont work

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have function which gets some data from the user, creates a struct using them and adds the struct to a linked list. but it does not save data to the linked list:

```
typedef struct contact Contact;
typedef Contact *ContactPtr;
int main(){        
    ContactPtr starPtr;
    addContact(starPtr);
    printf("## %s", starPtr->firstName);
    return 0;
}
void addContact(ContactPtr sPtr){
printf("\n FF:\n");
ContactPtr newPtr;
ContactPtr prevPtr;
ContactPtr currentPtr;
newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Contact));
char fN[20];
char sN[20];
char phN[12];
scanf("%s", &fN);
scanf("%s", &sN);
scanf("%s", &phN);

if (newPtr!=NULL){
    strcpy(newPtr->firstName, fN);
    strcpy(newPtr->surName, sN);
    strcpy(newPtr->phoneNo, phN);


    newPtr->next=NULL;
    prevPtr = NULL;
    currentPtr=sPtr;

    while(currentPtr!=NULL){

        prevPtr=currentPtr;
        currentPtr=currentPtr->next;
    }

    if(prevPtr==NULL){
            printf("!!@");
        newPtr->next=sPtr;
        sPtr=newPtr;
    }
    else{
        prevPtr->next=newPtr;
        newPtr->next=currentPtr;
    }
}
else{
printf("$$WRONG");
}
}
```

Program returns null for `starPtr->firstName`.
Is this problem for the function or the linked list? and is it pointing to the right value?

Comment: step through your code with a debugger. your 'add to list' logic seems to be off. with a debugger, you can see what's happening at every step, and compare that to what you expect

Comment: In function `void addContact(ContactPtr sPtr)`, you have `sPtr=newPtr;`. This change will be effective in the scope of the function, but not in the `main`, since functions work on copies. Change for `void addContact(ContactPtr* sPtr)` and modify `*sPtr`.

Comment: there is a nice linked list guide at http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Comment: @francis : I think the pointer type is typedefd in the code.

Comment: @limekin : Right. Yet, if you wish to modify a pointer to something in a function, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer to something. `void fun(whatever a){a=b;}` is useless, whatever `a` is. The function `void fun(whatever* a){*a=b;}` does something.

Comment: @francis : You are right, but by typedefd I meant "ContactPtr" in that code actually means "struct contact *", so the function signature actually is "void addContact(struct contact *sPtr)". Or I got the two typedefs on the first two lines of the code wrong ?

Comment: you *need* a pointer to pointer, in order to set the value of the pointer in the function

Comment: Ah now I got it, thanks for correcting me. Sorry for the bother !

Answer (score 2):

In `main`, you have:

```
ContactPtr starPtr;
addContact(starPtr);
```

And `addContact` is defined as:

```
void addContact(ContactPtr sPtr){
```

There is no way how `addContact` could modify `startPtr`, that's why it is never pointing to anything useful.

If it would be C++, you could change your code to:

```
void addContact(ContactPtr& sPtr){
```

With this, you are passing a reference to `startPtr`, and it can be modified inside `addContact`.

But if it is C, you have to use a pointer to a pointer, like

```
void addContact(ContactPtr* sPtr){
```

Inside `addContact`, replace `sPtr` with `*sPtr`.

Change `main` like this:

```
addContact(&starPtr);
```